# What is the difference between timeToFirstByte_s and timeTaken_s mean

Tags: azure-front-door

In Azure Portal, when I go under 'Azure Front Door' and click 'Logs' and execute this query

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| take 10
```

I see the output tables has 2 columns `timeToFirstByte_s` and `timeTaken_s`.
What are the difference between them? I always see they have the same values in the output.

And when I see a high number (e.g. 10.01 sec). How can I debug further to understand why it takes so long?

Answer (score 0):

From [the Front Door logs documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-diagnostics?pivots=front-door-standard-premium):

> TimetoFirstByte - The length of time, in seconds, from when the Azure
> Front Door edge received the request to the time the first byte was
> sent to client, as measured by Azure Front Door. This property doesn't
> measure the client data.
>
> timeTaken - The length of time from when the Azure Front Door edge
> received the client's request to the time that Azure Front Door sent
> the last byte of the response to the client, in seconds. This field
> doesn't take into account network latency and TCP buffering.